# targetting deeply nested arrays in JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to list an actor name element with the following JSON format with angular js:

```
   {movies: [
    title: "Movie Title",
    actors: {
    list: [
    {
    name: "James Mason"
    },
    {
    name: "Kirk Douglas"
    },
    {
    name: "Paul Lukas"
    },
    {
    name: "Peter Lorre"
    }
    ]
    }]
   }
```

My parent ngrepeat element works with the top level element but can not access the actor names:

```
        <ul ng-repeat="movie in items.movies">
          <li>
            <b>Title: </b> {{movie.title}}<br>
            <b>Actor list:</b> 
           <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="actor in movie.actors">
              {{actor.list.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I have also tried the following:
`<li>{{movie.actors['list'][0].name}}</li>`

But the above only grabs the first name. I find the nesting very complicated to access with angularjs so if you could see something I am not, can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You still need to loop through 'list'

Add one more repeat.
ng-repeat="name in actor.list"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
<li ng-repeat="actor in movie.actors.list">{{actor.name}}</li>
```